# INDEX MATCH Combination with cell referencing which tab to look up

Tags: indexing, match, excel-2010

I was looking to use a VLOOKUP combined with a HLOOKUP, but I've since found that I'd be better off using a combination of INDEX and MATCH. I've searched everywhere and have come close, but I'm still stuck.

What I want to do is look up the type of leave (C2:P2) and employee name (B4 in my example), and if POSSIBLE, refer to cell B1 (currently showing January 2013) which would be the tab that I wish to retrieve the information from (tabs to select from are January 2013, February 2013, March 2013, April 2013, and YTD).

[Link to screengrab](http://s797.photobucket.com/user/magandaangels/media/Stack%20Exchange%20Screengrabs/INDEXMATCHNotEvaluating.jpg.html)

I hope this is clear - please let me know if anything doesn't make sense!

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry - I worked it out with a bit of trial and error.

```
=INDEX(YTD!$B$4:$O$100,MATCH($B6,YTD!$A$4:$A$108,0),MATCH(C$4,YTD!$B$3:$O$3,0))
```

Thankyou  : )